# Using valueForKeyPath to grab specific data

Tags: ios

```
Printing description of self->data:
{
    root =     {
        participant =         (
                        {
                age =                 {
                    text = "\n        27";
                };
                class =                 {
                    text = "\n        M 25-29";
                };
                gender =                 {
                    text = "\n        M";
                };
            },
                        {
                age =                 {
                    text = "\n        27";
                };
                class =                 {
                    text = "\n        M 25-29";
                };
                gender =                 {
                    text = "\n        M";
                };
            },
                        {
                age =                 {
                    text = "\n        29";
                };
                class =                 {
                    text = "\n        M 25-29";
                };
                gender =                 {
                    text = "\n        M";
                };
            },
```

There's an example of my data. The real record is 913 items in length consisting of male and female *participants*. How do I whittle a dict down to just the Males or Females?

I've tried `valueForKeyPath:@"root.participant.gender.text==M"` but that's not it. I specifically just want to know the `class` for Males and Females respectively in case there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was working so I ended up going with this

```
NSArray *participants = [self.data valueForKeyPath:@"root.participant"];
NSMutableArray *men = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *women = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *p in participants) {
    NSString *t = [XMLReader cleanString:[p valueForKeyPath:@"chiptime.text"]];
    NSNumber *m = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self timeToMinutes:t]];
    if([[XMLReader cleanString:[p valueForKeyPath:@"gender.text"]] isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
        [men addObject:m];
    } else {
        [women addObject:m];
    }
}
```

The `XMLReader cleanString` just takes out the `\n\s*` garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[[self valueForKeyPath:@"root.participant.gender.text"] isEqualToString:@"\n        M"`  (quotes do not enclose the whole expression and `-isEqualToString:` is used) instead of`valueForKeyPath:@"root.participant.gender.text==M"`.

Comment: `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSString *'. Any ideas?

Comment: it's not happy because that's passing an `NSString` method to an `NSArray` => `-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9400c50`

Comment: Use self.data instead of self and let me know the result